# Oracle Apex - SQL decode colon delimited list of values

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I'm not sure how best to go about this. Is it possible to decode each value in a colon delimited list?
Example:

```
emp
---
1:2:3:4

decode(emp, ('1','2','3','4'), ('a','b','c','d')) emp

result:

emp
------
a:b:c:d
```

But obviously this does not work. What would be the best course of action to achieve this?

Comment: listagg function shoud do the work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
    SELECT LISTAGG(ENAME, ', ')
     WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY hiredate, ENAME) "Emp_list",
   MIN(hiredate) "Earliest" FROM emp WHERE deptno = 30;
```

[image]

You can pick any delimiter.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much this work perfectly.